# MySQL, referential integrity doesn't work

Tags: mysql, referential-integrity

I use MySQL Server 5.5; MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE; WinXp SP3;
I created 2 tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Address` (
  `AddressID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Country` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Region` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `PostalCode` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL ,
  `Address1` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customers` (
  `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Email` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,
  `Password` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL ,
  `RegistrationDate` TIMESTAMP NULL ,
  `CustomerCellPhone` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `AddressID` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`) ,
  INDEX `AddressID_idx` (`AddressID` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `Email_UNIQUE` (`Email` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `CustomerAddressID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`AddressID` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Address` (`AddressID` )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Basically, the table ‘Customers’ contains foreign key constraint and it doesn't work.
Theoretically, if I insert the data into two tables, I won’t delete ‘Address’ because ‘Customers’ depends on it:

```
insert into Address SET Country = 'Zimbabwe',
                        City = 'Harare',
                        Region = 'Mashonaland East Province',
                        PostalCode = '777',
                        Address1 = 'square 777 - 777';

insert into Customers SET FirstName = 'John',
                          LastName ='Doe',
                          Email = 'john@doe.com',
                          Password = '12345',
                          RegistrationDate = now(),
                          CustomerCellPhone = 123456789,
                          AddressID = 1;
```

'Customers'

> ```
> CustomerID    FirstName   AddressID
> 1             John        1
> ```

'Address'

> ```
> AddressID         Country          City   
> 1                 Zimbabwe         Harare
> ```

But, I can delete the address of my customer by:

```
DELETE FROM Address WHERE AddressID=1;
```

the table 'Customers' refer to nothing (dangling pointer)

> ```
> CustomerID        FirstName       AddressID
> 1                 John            1
> ```

the empty table 'Address'

> ```
> AddressID         Country         City    
> ---               ---             ---
> ```

The problem is ‘Customers’ refer to NULL into ‘Address’, because ‘Address’.AddressID = 1 doesn’t exist. It doesn't give me any errors. What I can do to repair this bug?

Comment: What version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: Just replace `ON DELETE RESTRICT` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: If you want to restrict deletion - use ON DELETE RESTRICT; just check that foreign key has DELETE rule - RESTRICT, not SET NULL. Also, it was strange that all field values became NULL. Are there any triggers that could do it?

Comment: Just replace the keyword didn’t help me. The point is the MySQL allow me to delete the data which refer to another table - it isn’t right.

Comment: @Devart, yes, I use no one trigger and set 'on delete restrict'. I also tried to implement basic tutorial which doesnt' work at my computer: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/2248101/Referential-Integrity-in-MySQL.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew, restart the MySQL Server helps me.